# the pipes don"t send the tab

Tags: c, pipe, fork

In my code, i have to use several pipes, the father must send each sons an interval, and in this interval the son must search prime numbers.

the problem is that the interval sent by the father is not received by the sons.
this is my code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int p = 4;
    const int n = 500;

    int k, i, j;
    int premier;

    pid_t fils[p];
    int tubePere[2], tubeFils[p][2], intervals1[2], intervals2[2];

    pipe(tubePere);
    for (k = 0; k < p; k++)
    {
        pipe(tubeFils[p]);
        fils[k] = fork();
        intervals1[0] = k * n/p + 1;
        intervals1[1] = (k + 1) * n/p;
        printf("intervals1 : %d .. %d\n",intervals1[0], intervals1[1]);
        close(tubeFils[k][0]);
        write(tubeFils[k][1], intervals1, sizeof(intervals1));
        if (fils[k] == 0)
        {
            close(tubeFils[k][1]);
            read(tubeFils[k][0],  intervals2, sizeof(intervals2));
            printf("intervals2 : %d .. %d\n",intervals2[0], intervals2[1]);
            for (i = intervals1[0]; i <= intervals2[1]; i++)
            {
                if (i == 1)
                    premier = 0;
                else if (i == 2)
                    premier = 1;
                else
                {
                    j = 2;
                    premier = 1;
                    while ((j <= sqrt(i)) && (premier == 1))
                    {
                        if ((i%j) == 0)
                            premier = 0;
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                if (premier == 1)
                {
                   //printf("%d  ",i);
                }
            }
            exit(0);

        }
        else if (fils[k] == -1)
            printf("Error\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I displayed the intervals received by the sons and send by the father

```
intervals1 : 1 .. 125
intervals1 : 126 .. 250
intervals1 : 251 .. 375
intervals1 : 376 .. 500
intervals1 : 1 .. 125
intervals1 : 126 .. 250
intervals1 : 251 .. 375
intervals1 : 376 .. 500
intervals2 : 0 .. 255
intervals1 : 1 .. 125
intervals1 : 126 .. 250
intervals1 : 251 .. 375
intervals2 : 0 .. 255
intervals1 : 1 .. 125
intervals1 : 126 .. 250
intervals2 : 0 .. 255
intervals1 : 1 .. 125
intervals2 : 0 .. 255
```

Comment: I think the write() part should also be in a condition. Right now, each child would execute the commands to close the read end of the pipe and to write to the write end, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the pere `write` in *both* pere and fil instead of *only* in pere.

Your second pipe call is `pipe(tubefils[p])` but it needs to be `pipe(tubefils[k])`

You should do `wait` at the end of pere.

And, you should close the write end of the pipe in the parent after doing the write.

And, you should close the read end of the pipe in the child after doing the read.

---

Here's some corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
main(void)
{
    const int p = 4;
    const int n = 500;

    int k, i, j;
    int premier;

    pid_t pid;
    pid_t fils[p];
    int tubePere[2], tubeFils[p][2], intervals1[2], intervals2[2];

    pipe(tubePere);
    for (k = 0; k < p; k++) {
#if 0
        pipe(tubeFils[p]);
#else
        pipe(tubeFils[k]);
#endif

        pid = fork();
        fils[k] = pid;

        if (pid < 0) {
            printf("Error\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // pere ...
        if (pid != 0) {
            intervals1[0] = k * n / p + 1;
            intervals1[1] = (k + 1) * n / p;
            printf("intervals1 : %d .. %d\n", intervals1[0], intervals1[1]);
            close(tubeFils[k][0]);
            write(tubeFils[k][1], intervals1, sizeof(intervals1));
            close(tubeFils[k][0]);
            continue;
        }

        // fils ...
        close(tubeFils[k][1]);
        read(tubeFils[k][0], intervals2, sizeof(intervals2));
        close(tubeFils[k][0]);

        printf("intervals2 : %d .. %d\n", intervals2[0], intervals2[1]);

        for (i = intervals1[0]; i <= intervals2[1]; i++) {
            if (i == 1)
                premier = 0;
            else if (i == 2)
                premier = 1;
            else {
                j = 2;
                premier = 1;
                while ((j <= sqrt(i)) && (premier == 1)) {
                    if ((i % j) == 0)
                        premier = 0;
                    j++;
                }
            }
            if (premier == 1) {
                // printf("%d ",i);
            }
        }
        exit(0);
    }

    while (1) {
        pid = wait(NULL);
        if (pid <= 0)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the corrected output:

```
intervals2 : 1 .. 125
intervals1 : 1 .. 125
intervals2 : 126 .. 250
intervals1 : 1 .. 125
intervals1 : 126 .. 250
intervals1 : 251 .. 375
intervals2 : 376 .. 500
intervals1 : 1 .. 125
intervals1 : 126 .. 250
intervals2 : 251 .. 375
intervals1 : 1 .. 125
intervals1 : 126 .. 250
intervals1 : 251 .. 375
intervals1 : 376 .. 500
```